# Как привязать кнопку к смене фильтра у трех картинок сразу?

Tags: button

Добрый день. Я новичок в [js](/questions/tagged/js) и пытаюсь решить такое задание.

Есть программа что-то вроде фоторобота. И сверху над картинкой создаю две кнопки с изменением на позитив и негатив фоток через фильтр `invert` Но почему то пишет что кнопка ссылается на `null`. Помогите чтобы кнопки заработали

```
<script>
function pozitiv() {
        document.getElementById("#vse").style.filter = 'invert: 0%';};
        function negativ(image) {
        document.getElementById("#vse").style.filter = 'invert: 100%';}
</script>
<body>
<input type="button" onclick="pozitiv()" value="Позитив"/>
<input type="button" onclick="negativ()" value="Негатив"/>
<div id="vse">
<div>
    <button onclick="slider.right();"><</button>    
    <div class="maindiv">
        <div id="scr"></div>
    </div> 
    <button onclick="slider.left();">></button>
</div>
<div>
    <button onclick="slider1.right();"><</button>   
    <div class="maindiv">
        <div id="scr1"></div>
    </div> 
    <button onclick="slider1.left();">></button>
</div>
<div>
    <button onclick="slider2.right();"><</button>   
    <div class="maindiv">
        <div id="scr2"></div>
    </div> 
    <button onclick="slider2.left();">></button>
</div>
</div>
</body>
```

Comment: вместо `invert: 0%;` напишите `invert(0)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема в следующем.

Вы в этом куске

```
document.getElementById("#vse")
```

Пытаетесь получить доступ к элементу `id="#vse"`.

Что бы заработало нужно поправить на

```
document.getElementById("vse")
```

Answer (score 0):

Вы пытаетесь получить элемент с `id="#vse"`.

Предлагаю вам использовать следующие варианты:

- `document.getElementById('vse')`
- `document.querySelector('#vse')`

Подробнее:

- [`.getElementById()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById)
- [`.querySelector()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector)